# UITableView Find Location of Section header?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to find out the location of a swipeGesture when swiped on a tableview.
In the swipe action, I've seen many people do this:

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:tableView];
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But my tableView is made up of section headers that have no cells in them. Because of that, the index path method returns nil. Is there any way to find the location of the Section header? They don't have this method, but something like `indexPathForSectionAtPoint:` would be the kind of thing I'm looking for.
If anybody knows how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: An `indexPath` has both the `section` and `row` information in it... e.g.  `NSInteger section = indexPath.section;`

Comment: Yes but because there are no rows in the table at that moment, the method returns nil

Comment: If there are no rows then the section will have no height so how can someone tap inside an area with no height?

Comment: Sorry I meant to clarify that I am looking for section headers

Comment: @Paul It can have a section header, even with no rows.

Comment: Construct the section header as a view and put a gesture recognizer on it...

Comment: That's what I had originally. But because each gesture recognized was quite small (only 45 pixels tall), it was very hard to get a swipe. Putting it on the whole table view doesn't require the swipe to be exactly on one of the headers.

Comment: Hey Kyle, have you found a solution to this yet? I'm looking to do the same thing..

Answer (score 1):

You already have the `location` and the `indexPath`.
Now, to get the cell (and its data) you use `indexPath.row`, as in your example.
To get the section (with or without cell) you use `indexPath.section`.

If there is no row beneath the point `location` `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` will return `nil`, so that is expected behavior.

Section headings are not really meant to be areas of the view for interaction. Rather they are headings. The `UITableView` is designed to respond to interaction with its rows.

Maybe one way to fix this is to change your data structure so that the content you display in your section headings really lives in table view rows.

Another approach would be to use the `UIView` of the section header and have it respond to the swipe gesture. (Make sure you pass the gesture on to the table view with `super`.)

Comment: I apologize for I wasn't very clear in my original post, but the index path is nil because there are no visible rows in the table

Comment: Thanks, I need to keep my section headers because my app's table view works kind of like an accordion. When the headers are tapped, they open up and reveal rows. In an earlier attempt I had the gesture recognizers in the individual sections but this didn't work because I think the table view was receiving the touches first and they were quite small, making it very difficult to get a swipe.what do you mean when you say pass the gesture on to the table with super? Thanks for the help

Comment: `super` would apply if you were to use `touchesBegan:`. That is one way to send the touch to another object on a back layer.

Comment: I used your approach at the end (using the UIView of the section header) and attached my gesture there. Works perfectly.

Comment: Great. Don't forget to tick the checkbox above.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing something similar, but with a tap gesture on the table section header (instead of swipe).

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but I basically convert the gesture's `view` to the `tableView` coordinate space.  Then I iterate over each section header's `CGRect` to see if it intersects with the gesture origin.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("header") as! HeaderCell
    let tapHeader = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedOnHeader:")
    tapHeader.delegate = self
    tapHeader.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapHeader.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapHeader)
    return cell
}

func tappedOnHeader(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer){
    if let cellContentView = gesture.view {
        let tappedPoint = cellContentView.convertPoint(cellContentView.bounds.origin, toView: tableView)
        for i in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
            let sectionHeaderArea = tableView.rectForHeaderInSection(i)
            if CGRectContainsPoint(sectionHeaderArea, tappedPoint) {
                print("tapped on section header:: \(i)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Created a git branch on another tutorial project as a working example:

https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/HorizontalScrollingCollectionView/tree/sectionHeaderTap

Answer (score -1):

```
//Sublcass a header footer view and in .h file declare this protocol
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)userTappedView:(UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view atPoint:(CGPoint)point;

@end

//in same .h file add this
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MyProtocol> delegate;

//In same subclass .m file do this
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];

    [self.delegate userTappedView:self atPoint:point];
}

//In controller containing tableview, conform to 'MyProtocol' like this
-(void)userTappedView:(UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view atPoint:(CGPoint)point {

    NSNumber *value = [self sectionForUserSelectionInTableView:self.tableView
                                               atTouchLocation:point
                                            inHeaderFooterView:view];

    if (!value) {
        return;
    }

    NSUInteger tappedSection = value.integerValue;

}

-(NSNumber *)sectionForUserSelectionInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                                atTouchLocation:(CGPoint)location
                             inHeaderFooterView:(UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view {

    CGPoint point = [tableView convertPoint:location
                                   fromView:view];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
        CGRect rect = [tableView rectForHeaderInSection:i];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)) {
            return @(i);
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```